# Adding an Array of Tasks (PHP App Engine)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-tasks

I have a `foreach` loop that goes through a list, and for each item on that list, I want to add a task.

Currently I have this:

```
use google\appengine\api\taskqueue\PushTask;

foreach($list_array as $list)
{
    $list_id = $list['id'];
    $task = new PushTask('/task', ['list_id' => $list_id]);
    $task_name = $task->add();
}
```

I am assuming it would be a far better move to run the `->add()` after all the tasks have been declared. Could anyone give their 2 cents on how I could achieve this or is the way I am doing it fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For all who is interested, here is what I did.

```
use google\appengine\api\taskqueue\PushTask;
use google\appengine\api\taskqueue\PushQueue;

$tasks = array();

//find each billable user and add them to a task
foreach($list_array as $list)
    $tasks[] = new PushTask('/task', ['list_id' => $list_id]);

$queue = new PushQueue();
$queue->addTasks($tasks);
```